# hibernate self referencing table get rows by fk

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

```
table Student
----------------
id  | somecolumn with string| fk(which is self referencing ID of the same table)
```

how can i make hibernate query that will fetch all items where value of id will match value of fk.

here is what i have tried but it doesn't works (it returns only 1 result instead of result set)

```
List<Student> list = (List<Student>) sessionFactory
            .getCurrentSession()
            .createQuery("from Student p join p.studentFKs p2 where p2.id = :parentId")
            .setParameter("parentId", parentId).list();
```

can someone help me solve the mistery? i know that it can be achieved with Hibernate criterias also.

UPDATE answer is to change query to(join was invalid.. ):

```
select p from Student p join p.student p2 where p2.id = :parentId
```

Comment: can you post your entity class here?

Comment: Answer was to change query. Not to join by hash set, but to join by that same class type since it is self referencing table. I updated my question with answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i use something like this and this is work

property of join inside entity Student :

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
private Set<Student> testJoins = new HashSet<Student>();
```

HQL to get that set :

```
select a.testJoins from Student a where a.id = :parentId
```

maybe you can change your query from `p2.id = :parentId` to-->> `p.id = :parentId`

Comment: i have already solved it, and the answer was in changing the query `from Student p join p.studentFKs p2 where p2.id = :parentId`

to `select p from Student p join p.student p2 where p2.id = :parentId`